# ODBC connection to Access 365 database

Tags: jdbc, odbc, office365, driver

I've read many other thereads on this issue but all quite old (now working on Win 10 and Access 365).
I have installed the drivers (from MS -  Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 64 bits), configured the ODBC connection but no way of finding the drivers.

I can't use ucanacess becaure jackcess does not support some functions (i.e. ALTER TABLE), so I'm a little  lost. Thanks for helping

Comment: "no way of finding the drivers" - Search for answers referring to "odbcad32.exe". If you really have installed the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 64 bits" then it should appear in the "Drivers" tab when you run `%SystemRoot%\System32\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: You can also use [AceOdbcCheck](https://github.com/gordthompson/AceOdbcCheck) to see if the ACE driver is installed correctly.